# $viewValue is not applying in textbox directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Try to create masking**
Console Print $viewValue is different but not apply in view.

> NgModelController {$viewValue: "656-56", $modelValue: "656565",
>   $$rawModelValue: "656565", $validators: Object, $asyncValidators:
>   Object…}

Code :

```
var app = angular.module("masking",[]);
app.directive('textbox', function mask() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { },
        bindToController: {
            model: "=ngModel",
        },
        controller: function($scope, $attrs) {

        },
        compile: function() {
            return {
                pre: function(scope, el, attrs) {
                },
                post: function(scope, element, attrs, Ctrls) {
                 }
            };
        },
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="Ctrl.model" /> </div> ',
        controllerAs: 'Ctrl',
    };
});

app.directive('angularMask', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: false,
      link: function ($scope, el, attrs, model) {
        $scope.$watch(function(){return attrs.angularMask;}, function(value) {
          if (model.$viewValue != null){
            model.$viewValue = mask(String(model.$viewValue).replace(/\D/g, ''));
            el.val(model.$viewValue);
          }
        });

        model.$formatters.push(function (value) {
          return value === null ? '' : mask(String(value).replace(/\D/g, ''));
        });

        model.$parsers.push(function (value) {
          model.$viewValue = mask(value);
          var modelValue = attrs.isModelValueEqualViewValues ? model.$viewValue : String(value).replace(/\D/g, '');
          el.val(model.$viewValue);
          return modelValue;
        });

        function mask(val) {
                    console.log(model);

          var format = attrs.angularMask,
          arrFormat = format.split('|');

          if (arrFormat.length > 1) {
            arrFormat.sort(function (a, b) {
              return a.length - b.length;
            });
          }

          if (val === null || val == '') {
            return '';
          }
          var value = String(val).replace(/\D/g, '');
          if (arrFormat.length > 1) {
            for (var a in arrFormat) {
              if (value.replace(/\D/g, '').length <= arrFormat[a].replace(/\D/g, '').length) {
                format = arrFormat[a];
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          var newValue = '';
          for (var nmI = 0, mI = 0; mI < format.length;) {
            if (!value[nmI]) {
              break;
            }
            if (format[mI].match(/\D/)) {
              newValue += format[mI];
            } else {
              newValue += value[nmI];
              nmI++;
            }
            mI++;
          }
          return newValue;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

HTML Code

```
<textbox ng-model="myModelPhone" angular-mask="000-000-000"></textbox>
    {{myModelPhone}}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amitme/s0Lenp0w/1/ here is jsfiddle link

Comment: `angular-mask="000-000-000"` directive should be applied on innner template

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar yes, but how can I apply inside template ?

Comment: please check below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you shouldn't be applying `angular-mask` directive over a same element where you had used `textbox` directive. Because If you placed it over `ngModel` of the `textbox` model not the inner `ngModelController`.

You need to change your directive structure little. from `textbox` directive just pass masking pattern in attribute like `masking-pattern="000-000-000"`

and then change the directive template to

```
template: function(element, attrs){
   return '<div><input type="text" ng-model="Ctrl.model" angular-mask="'+attrs.maskingPattern+'"/> </div> '
}
```

**HTML**

```
Text box directive : <textbox ng-model="myModelPhone" masking-pattern="000-000-000"></textbox>
{{myModelPhone}}
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9smpa6s/)

Comment: that means, if I have to load templates according to attrs.angularPattern is present then load angular-mask template otherwise load without angular-mask. or any better way to do

Comment: yes, you could do that, Either way you could pass them inside isolated `scope` of your directive..

Comment: @Amit does my answer helped you?

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Parkar... Sorry for late reply.. facing no internet problem.
Yes your answer is help full. and Actually I don't want to load separate template for this, can you tell how we can do that with isolated scope.

Comment: Actually I don't want to load separate template for this, can you tell how we can do that with isolated scope. because facing some issues in isolated scope.

Comment: What issues you are facing with isolated scope?

Comment: In isolated scope  masking value getting undefined

Comment: Could you please provide me a plunkr with a problem..answer plunkr works perfectly..

Comment: Actually my mask directive executed first and then my textbox directive so I am not getting any value in isolated scope. Please have a look @Pankaj Parkar. this is jsfiddle link

[https://jsfiddle.net/amitme/z7schq35/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/amitme/z7schq35/2/)

help is really appreciated... thanks